# Is there an easy way to get a subset for a many to many relationship?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have a relationship
Order(1) => Item(Many)=> distribtuion(Many) => recipients(Many)

Is there an effiecient way using linq to entities (EF4) to get :

- a) all recipients for an order?
- b)
  all items for a recipient for an
  order?

This is my solution current solution for a:

```
   List<Distribution> distributions = new List<Distribution>();
   List<Recipient> recipients = new List<Recipient>();
    foreach (OrderItem oi in  order.OrderItems)
                {
                    foreach (Distribution d in oi.Distributions)
                        if (!distributions.Contains(d))
                        {
                            distributions.Add(d);
                            foreach (Recipient r in d.Recipients)
                                if (!recipients.Contains(r))
                                    recipients.Add(r);
                        }

                }
```

I am thinking there should be a way for me to get Order.Orderitems.Distribution.Recipients with a single linq query but maybe i am wrong.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to use the 2 way properties to do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<Recipient> orderRecipients = 
    Entities.Recipients.Where(r => r.Distribution.Item.OrderID == OrderID);
```

with a similar thing for (b) depending on your actual entity names and foreign keys.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but when I went to code it those subsets do not exist.

Comment: You need a foreign key linking the tables in the database and to select the checkbox `Include foreign key columns in the model` when selecting `Update Model from Database` in your edmx model.

Comment: The table exists but EF4 hides it.